# 2+ op amps in Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, opamp

The following code yields the attached picture. What adjustments should be made so that resistor R3 would be directly connected to op2.-? I know what's wrong in the code, but to idea to how to fix it

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0) node[op amp] (op1) {}
(op1.-) to[short,*-*] ++(-0.8,0)
to [R,l=$R_1$,*-*] (-3.8,0.5) node(ex){}
(op1.-)++(-0.8,0) to[short] ++(0,1.5) coordinate(rightC1)
to [C,l=$C_1$] ( rightC1 -| ex)
to [short] (ex)
to [short,*-o] ++ (-0.5,0)
(op1.-) to[short,*-] ++(0,1.5) coordinate (leftC)
to[C,l=$C_2$] (leftC -| op1.out)
to[short,-*] (op1.out)
to [short,-o] ++(0.5,0) coordinate(end)
(op1.+) to ++(0,-1) node[cground]{}
(op1.-) to[short,*-] ++(0,3) coordinate (leftR)
to[R,l=$R_2$] (leftR -| op1.out)
to[short,-*] (op.out)
(end) to[R,l=$R_3$,o-*] ++ (3,0)%-----------------------------error here
node[op amp] (op2){}%-----------------------------------------error here
(op2.-) to [short,-*] ++(0,1.5) coordinate (leftC2)
to [R,l=$R_4$] (leftC2 -| op2.out)
to [short,-*] (op2.out)
to [short,-o] ++ (0.5,0)
(op2.+) to ++(0,-1) node[cground]{};
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow a single path for everything. Is there any reason for such economical usage? You have say `op1` instead of `op` line before those error locations

Comment: No. Just that every example I've seen is drawn like that, so I assumed every possible circuit can be made similarly.

Comment: Break those paths and you can connect anything to anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the advice giver by the commenter, I "broke" the 2 paths, and ended up with what I wanted. Here's the code in case someone out there is looking for something similar.

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0) node[op amp] (op1) {}
(op1.-) to[short,*-*] ++(-0.8,0)
to [R,l=$R_1$,*-*] (-3.8,0.5) node(ex){}
(op1.-)++(-0.8,0) to[short] ++(0,1.5) coordinate(rightC1)
to [C,l=$C_1$] ( rightC1 -| ex)
to [short] (ex)
to [short,*-o] ++ (-0.5,0) coordinate(ex1)
(op1.-) to[short,*-] ++(0,1.5) coordinate (leftC)
to[C,l=$C_2$] (leftC -| op1.out)
to[short,-*] (op1.out)
to [short,-o] ++(0.5,0) coordinate(end)
(op1.+) to ++(0,-1) node[cground]{}
(op1.-) to[short,*-] ++(0,3) coordinate (leftR)
to[R,l=$R_2$] (leftR -| op1.out)
to[short,-*] (op.out);
\draw %----------------------------------------------Change
(end)++(3.5,-0.5)node[op amp] (op2){}
(end) to[R,l=$R_3$,o-*] (op2.-)
(op2.-) to [short,-*] ++(0,1.5) coordinate (leftC2)
to [R,l=$R_4$] (leftC2 -| op2.out)
to [short,-*] (op2.out)
to [short,-o] ++ (0.5,0) coordinate(end2)
(op2.+) to ++(0,-0.5) node[cground]{}
(end)++(0,-2) to[open, v=$e$] ++(0,2)
(end2)++(0,-2)to[open, v=$e_o$] ++(0,2)
(ex1)++(0,-2.5) to[open,v^>=$e_i$]++(0,2.5);
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image: Never mind the dot before R4.]